# i have two table with foreign key and i want to press in foreign key in first table and the second table appear data

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have two blocks. First one is wizard and second is manual in Oracle Forms 11g with relational.

I execute the data into first block and I want to press in foreign key in first table and the second table appear data which is link together by the same number foreign key?

Which trigger should I use please? And which code should I put into trigger?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE` trigger at block level of `Block1` with code :

```
declare
 v_skulist  table1.skulist%type;
begin
 v_skulist := :Block1.f_skulist; --> represents left uppermost field
 go_block('Block2');
 execute_query;
 go_block('Block1'); --> go back to the upper block again, if don't want to come back, then starting from this line upto `end;`(exclusive) should be removed.
 while v_skulist != :Block1.f_skulist
 loop
  next_record;
 end loop;
end;
```

where

- `Query Data Source Name` property is set to `table1` for `Block1`

  and
- `Query Data Source Name` property is set to `myuser1.table2` with
  `WHERE Clause` set to

  `skulist = :Block1.skulist` for `Block2`
  assuming the second table is on the other user at least

  with granted `select` privilege to your current user as mentioned in your comment.

This way, whatever record touched in the first block, the counterpart foreign key column is brought in the second block.

Answer (score 0):

You should have used the **data block wizard** which creates all necessary triggers and procedures that take care about it.

If you're going to do it manually, well ... you probably shouldn't do that, there are too many procedures involved.

I suggest you remove detail block and create it from scratch, this time using the wizard. Pay attention to what it asks and - once you're done - the form will automatically do what you want it to.

Then, you can review what objects Forms created for you and - if you really REALLY want to do it manually, try to mimic its steps.

Comment: ok if the second block in database but it in another user how will it appear in my user to connect it with first block ???

Comment: If you are saying that the second (detail) block's underlying table belongs to another user, then you have to acquire (at least) SELECT privileges from that user (see GRANT statement). Then, create a **synonym** to it in your own schema so that you could use it in the data block wizard.